# Not aligning denominator ahead of time breaks the equation, why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Why can I not align the denominator later on? (it gives me completely different values)

[image]

I thought I already got this down pat, but I guess not. Can someone point me to where my knowledge gap is, and where I need to brush up?

Comment: They are not completely different values, just two ways of writing the same value. Simply expand the brackets and see.

Comment: What is the working to equate them? I can't seem to figure it out. Checking against Wolframalpha, the graphed curves seems not exactly equal: [Wolframalpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+2%2F3+*+%285%2F%28%281%2B2%2F3x%29%29%2B2%29+%3D+15%2F%283%2B2x%29+%2B2+%3F)

Comment: Why are you comparing it to the wrong multiple choice answer?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, I'm failing to understand how they got 15 as the numerator...

Comment: Multiply the fraction by 3/3 to get rid of the fraction in the denominator, so $\frac5{1+2i/3} = \frac33 \frac5{1+2i/3} = \frac{3\times5}{3(1+2i/3)} = \frac{15}{3+2i}$.

Comment: I see, I think I got confused with the \frac{2}{3}. I should have sorted out the denominator first by multiplying the fraction by \frac{3}{3}. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are actually the same! When you expand the top expression, you should get the bottom one. Note the bottom expression is under the category *Alternate forms,* so they are all the same, just written in different forms.

Comment: What is the working to equate them? I can't seem to figure it out. Checking against Wolframalpha, the graphed curves seems not exactly equal: [Wolframalpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+2%2F3+*+%285%2F%28%281%2B2%2F3x%29%29%2B2%29+%3D+15%2F%283%2B2x%29+%2B2+%3F). What is my gap/am I missing here.